# Windows SSH client that allows hostkey via command line?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, plink

So we know that you can provide the hostkeys for putty via the registry, but this is annoying and painful if you are trying to automate things. WinSCP allows you to do this via the -hostkey switch, but I need a full terminal client with the same functionality.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So kitty has the -convert-dir switch, which can read the hostkeys from a folder

Comment: And bitvise tunnelier has a -hostKeysFile param, which can take a file, but both of these are less than ideal

Answer (score 0):

What about `ssh` under Cygwin? (See the `VERIFYING HOST KEYS` section of the [SSH manual](http://www.openssh.org/manual.html). The default Cygwin shell looks a bit rubbish but check out `mintty` - integrates really well into the Windows GUI.

Comment: In fact the mintty site says it's based on the non-networking parts of PuTTY's code and improves on PuTTY issues: http://code.google.com/p/mintty/wiki/PuttyIssues

Comment: I started using it instead of PuTTY because changing tabs in Vim using the Ctrl + PgUp/PgDown shortcut doesn't work in PuTTY (as mentioned on that link).

Comment: Still, thats using known_hosts in the .ssh folder. Bear in mind I'm tyring to automate this proces, so any extra steps (writing out to a config file etc) are extra steps that I would prefer not to perform if I can just pass it into the app via a command line switch